# Using Ajax in Wordpress to send mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to use Ajax to send an email through a web form I created, but I'm lost. I have no idea how Ajax functions in Wordpress.

I firstly created an action

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
```

The function that's supposed to retrieve the data and send the mail is:

```
function wpse_sendmail()
{
    $for = like_escape($_POST['forwhat']);
    $email = like_escape($_POST['email']);
    $headers = 'From: '.$email ."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email;
    $message = like_escape($_POST['message_message']);
    $respond = like_escape($_POST['message_email']);

    wp_mail( "support@ontrgt.net", "(OTN) Support: ".$support, $message, $headers); 
}
```

Finally, the js is like so:

```
$("#contact-send").click(function(){
    var forwhat = $("#contact-for").val();
    var name = $("#contact-name").val();
    var email = $("#contact-email").val();

    $.post( "<?php echo esc_js( site_url() ) ?>", { siteWideMessage:"null", forwhat: forwhat, name: name, email:email }, function(){
            console.log("success");
    });
});
```

I'm not too sure what I'm missing here. Can someone help me understand Wordpress's Ajax process?

---

***UPDATE***

I updated my code to this so far:

PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );

function wpse_sendmail()
{
    $for = $_POST['forwhat'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $headers = 'From: '.$email ."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email;
    $message = $_POST['message_message'];
    $respond = $_POST['message_email'];

    /*if(wp_mail( "support@ontrgt.net", "(OTN) Support: ".$for, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "WOOHOO";
    }*/

    if($for)
    {
        //Just to see if there is any response.
        echo "Whoohoo";
    }

    die();
}
```

Js

```
$("#contact-send").click(function(){
    var forwhat = $("#contact-for").val();
    var name = $("#contact-name").val();
    var email = $("#contact-email").val();

    var data = { action:'siteWideMessage', forwhat:forwhat, name:name, email:email };
    $.post('<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>', data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

Wordpress is still not responding with my AJAX command. I'm using the inspect element, and I see no data being passed around.

Comment: It should be `action: 'siteWideMessage'` and the `url` needs to be to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: and where did `$support` came from anyway

Comment: What's up with `like_escape` ? That was used to escape sql

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18845/wp-mail-script-with-jquery-post, then: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At first you need to add two actions, one for the non-logged in user explicitly required to make it working, for example something like this (Basically in your `functions.php` file):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
```

Then, you need to make the request to the `admin-ajax.php` so in the `jQuery` function, you may use something like this:

```
$("#contact-send").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // if the clicked element is a link

    //...

    var data = { 'action':'siteWideMessage', 'more':'values' };

    $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Make sure you put `exit/die` at the end of your `handler` in server side, for example:

```
function wpse_sendmail()
{
    // Process the post data...
    
    if(wp_mail(...)) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'failed';
    }

    die();
}
```

In your `success` callback, the `response` variable will get the response sent from the server side, i.e. `success/failed`. There are better ways to do this (Using [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) etc). Read [this detailed article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/). Also, if you want to return a `json` response then you may use `$.json('url', data, func)`.

If you are confused then let me tell you that, you should make the request to `admin-ajax.php` and pass the `action` with the request and in this case it is `siteWideMessage`, so `WordPress` will call the `handler` that's registered using `add_action` hook and in your case it's `wpse_sendmail`.Eid Mubarak :-)

Comment: Did you put the code within `$("#contact-send").click(function(){...});`

Comment: Put `console.log('clicked')` inside the click handler before `e.preventDefault()` for making sure it's triggering the handler and also check the console for other errors.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. It's unable to reach the admin-ajax.php link. My JS is in a JS file, not in the same file as my php functions.

Comment: So I did a little more testing. The site is responding with the page's HTML with the `console.log(response);` I'm not too sure what that means.

Comment: What you get as `HTML` ? The `echo` should be response.

Comment: Tried the same code and got the response as `failed`.

Comment: @Sandra, which means your `mail` cal returned false (failed).

Comment: @TheAlpha Yes my mail call returns `0`. Do I need to include anything else to make mail function working.

Comment: Do i need to include any additional code regarding the `smtp` details to make it functional

Answer (score 4):

I had to do something slightly differently to get this to work.

First I added a hidden input on my template page and gave it the value of the ajax url like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ajax_url" value="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"/>
```

Then I had this in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );

function wpse_sendmail() {
  echo "hewwo world";

  die();
}
```

And my js in a seperate js file as such:

```
$("#submit-form").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // if the clicked element is a link

  $.post($("#ajax_url").val(), {
      action: 'siteWideMessage',
      // and the rest
  }, function(response) {
      // handle a successful response
      console.log(response)
  });

});
```

This works for me.

Comment: Revisiting this as this solution still works. Should be higher. 

Steps i took to make it work:   placed jquery in my jQuery on page, the Hidden field to page, and added to Functions, and worked - unlike many other longer AJAX methods. This works  to return your "echo" message meaning it IS fired. 10000% recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [wp_ajax_(action)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)), it looks like you simply need to set the `action` parameter to *"siteWideMessage"*. For example...

```
$.post(<?= json_encode(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) ?>, {
    action: 'siteWideMessage',
    // and the rest
}, function(response) {
    // handle a successful response
});
```

Comment: This isn't really getting me to understand Wordpress's AJAX structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the wordpress way, or you can do this the easy way. I would make a plugin to hold AJAX-handling code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: AJAX Receiver
*/


add_action('admin_menu', 'ajax_receiver_menu');
function ajax_receiver_menu() {
    $parent_slug = null; // Child of null, so this menu item has no link to it in the dashboard.
    $menu_title  = "AJAX Receiver menu"; // This menu title will not be visible.
    $page_title  = "AJAX_Receiver"; // No one will visit this page.
    $menu_slug   = 'ajax_receiver'; // This is the last part of the URL you post to.
    $callback    = 'ajax_receiver_menu_content';
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $callback);
}



function ajax_receiver_menu_content() {
    // check request variables, do other logic.
    echo "This is the response to your AJAX request.";
}
```

Then, you can send a normal post request.

```
$.post( "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ajax_receiver", { siteWideMessage:"null", forwhat: forwhat, name: name, email:email }, function(data){
        console.log(data); // You should see "This is the response to your AJAX request." in your console.
});
```

This is definitely not how you're "supposed" to do it, but I've found this to be much easier to work with. The critical part is that the submenu doesn't know if it's echoing "This is the response to your AJAX request" in response to an AJAX request, or a normal page request. In fact, you could point your browser to `"/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ajax_receiver"` and you would just see "This is the response to your AJAX request" in unstyled text at the top of your screen.